# CoreUI aside menu floating over main

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, core-ui

I'm using the admin template CoreUI. My layout is the basic one as described in the page https://coreui.io/v1/docs/layout/options/

I'm trying to have the **aside menu on the right** to open **floating over** the main content and not inline decreasing the width of main.

I've tried to remove *aside-menu-fixed*, add aside-menu-floating or absolute, but it doesn't work.

Is there a way to do it without modifying the CoreUI css?

Below the code snippet, but it doesn't work here on SO

```css
.app-header{background-color:#4B8BF4}
.sidebar{background-color:#FFCD42}
.app-footer{background-color:#DD4F43}
.aside-menu{background-color:#19A15F}
.main{background-color:#EEE}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@coreui/coreui@2.1.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@coreui/coreui@2.1.7/dist/css/coreui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@coreui/coreui@2.1.7/dist/js/coreui.min.js"></script>



<body class="app header-fixed sidebar-fixed aside-menu-fixed sidebar-lg-show">
  <header class="app-header navbar">
    <!-- Header content here -->
    <h2>I'm the header!</h2>
  </header>
  <div class="app-body">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <!-- Sidebar content here -->
      <nav class="sidebar-nav">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">
                            <i class="nav-icon icon-speedometer"></i> Dashboard
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-title">Settings</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
    </div>
    <main class="main">
      <h1>I'm the main content...</h1>
    </main>
    <aside class="aside-menu">
      <!-- Aside menu content here -->
    </aside>
  </div>
  <footer class="app-footer">
    <!-- Footer content here -->
  </footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`body` element:

- add class `aside-menu-off-canvas`
- and remove class `aside-menu-fixed`

hth

Comment: This worked for me. But it's displayed by default, and I'd like it to be collapsed at start.